# Is there an equivalent of mod_rewrite for Twisted web?

Tags: python, frameworks

I've been programming in PHP for a long time, and I've just recently decided to make the switch to Python. Of all the Python web frameworks, I settled on Twisted Web to build the framework of my startup.

However (and I know it sounds nitpicky), mod_rewrite was something that I really appreciated about Apache. I want the entire system written in Python, and not just bits and pieces written in PHP and Python: while a PHP frontend could work, I'd avoid it if it was at all possible.

Is it possible to build such an application without resorting to ugly urls?

Note: I am aware of the fact that Django allows URL rewriting, but it kinda defeats the purpose of using Twisted by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section of the [Twisted Documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#auto21) that mentions inspiration from Apache's mod_rewrite and lists some methods, specifically twisted.web.rewrite, to do similar things.